# How to make a variable that holds double qoutes

Tags: vb.net

The question is simple, How do I define a variable which holds double quotes. when I try to define the variable like this

`Dim s as String = "  " "` ,

VS  puts an extra quote like this

`Dim s as String = """"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra `"` is used to escape the `"` character, so the sequence of two double-quotes (`""`) will show up as `"` when your string is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have it correct with the 4 quotes, that is VBs way of escaping the quotes.  So, for example:

```
        Dim oneDoubleQuote As String = """"
    Dim twoDoubleQuotes As String = """"""
    MessageBox.Show("One:" & oneDoubleQuote)
    MessageBox.Show("Two:" & twoDoubleQuotes)
```

The first message box has One:"  and the second has Two:""

Comment: Is there any other character which I can use to escape

Comment: If you don't like the four quotes, then you could do:          Dim oneDoubleQuote As String = Chr(34)